# Macro to run query with preset variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write some VBA code that will export an MS Access query. 
I'd like it to be run it all from within Excel to source from a database I don't understand and don't want to tamper with. I just know I have to run a query and export it.

That's easy enough if the query doesn't rely on a user-input value to run (EG beginning/end dates) but if it needs input I can't find a good way to make that be set automatically.

I've seen some clever options here:

https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/466248-can-i-pass-parameters-macro-query

*A) Putting the SQL underlying the query within the VBA, but that can get very unwieldy, especially with big queries that I'm unfamiliar with. And TBH I don't **quite** understand the coding behind it- but that's just me being lazy...*

*B) Use a form on which to record the desired value- again unwieldy and also I can't change the query code.*

But I'd rather something along the lines of: cmdRun(QueryX,PARAM1,PARAM2). Is that wishful thinking?